# OpenCV VideoWriter C++ not Writing to Output.avi

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, video-processing, qimage

I'm attempting to write code that takes a frames and writes to an output file .avi / .mp4 using cv VideoWriter in C++.

System setup is Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Qt 5.9.5 (GCC 7.3.0, 64 bit)

I'm getting frames from camera, convert them to QImage and display them on GUI well.

```
    void FrameThread::run()
    {
      while (m_isWaitting)
      {
        if (SUCCESS == Buf_WaitForFrame(m_Cam, &m_frame))
        {
            int channels = m_frame.ucChannels;
            int width = m_frame.usWidth;
            int height = m_frame.usHeight;
            int elementBytes = m_frame.ucElemBytes;

            QImage img;

            img = QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);

            uchar *pSrc = (uchar *)m_frame.pBuffer + m_frame.usHeader;
            uchar *pDst = (uchar *)img.bits();
            if (2 == elementBytes)
            {
                pSrc += (elementBytes / 2);

                if (1 == channels)
                {
                    int pixels = width * height * channels;

                    for (int i = 0; i < pixels; ++i)
                    {
                        *pDst++ = *pSrc;
                        pSrc += elementBytes;
                    }
                }
            }

            emit signalUpdateImage(img);

            if (m_isSaving)
            {
                saveImage();
            }
            if (m_isRecording)
            {            
                if(!m_isCreateVideoWriter)
                {
                    QString savedPath = "/home/nvidia/Pictures/";
                    CvSize size = cvSize(2048, 1148);
                    char cur[1024];
                    timespec time;
                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
                    tm nowtm;
                    localtime_r(&time.tv_sec, &nowtm);
                    sprintf(cur, "%s%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d.avi", savedPath.toLocal8Bit().data(), nowtm.tm_year+1900, nowtm.tm_mon+1, nowtm.tm_mday, nowtm.tm_hour, nowtm.tm_min, nowtm.tm_sec);
                    video = cv::VideoWriter(cur,cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'),25.0, size, 1);
                    m_isCreateVideoWriter = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Clicked 'Stop Record' button
                    //Close video writer
                    if (CamObject::getInstance()->m_bFinishRec)
                    {
                        video.release();
                        m_isRecording = false;
                        m_isCreateVideoWriter = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    // Recording...
                    else
                    {
                        videoFrame = QImageToCvMat(img);
                        video.write(videoFrame);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I created method QImageToCvMat because their is not write method with QImage :

```
cv::Mat QImageToCvMat(QImage &inImage)
{
   cv::Mat mat(inImage.height(), inImage.width(),
            CV_8UC1, inImage.bits(), inImage.bytesPerLine());
  return mat;
}
```

The code failing to produce output and program collapse on line

```
video.write(videoFrame);
```

Any one familiar with this issue or can kindly give advice? Other way to create video file?

Comment: Can you try `imshow("test",videoFrame); waitKey(0);`  after   `videoFrame = QImageToCvMat(img);` I am suspicious about conversion

Comment: Also in conversion you begin with `inImage.height()` instead of `inImage.width()` width should come before height

Comment: Can you share the error message on collapse ?